# How consume REST service with complex type in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi service that calculates a price of a customized product. The controller function is:

```
public double Get([FromUri]Specifications specifications)
```

`Specifications` is a class that allows to customize the product:

```
public class Specifications 
{
    public string Currency;
    public int DesktopLicenses;
    public Product Product;
    public int Licenses;
}
```

Now, how can I consume this service from C#. I want to avoid to codify manually the URI query with all `Specifications` variables, I would like to able to use directly an instance of `Specifications`to call the service.

If the service is a POST, I could do it doing:

```
Specifications product = new Specifications( ...);
HttpResponseMessage reponse = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/pricecalculator", product).Result;
```

but I cannot find the way to do the same when I use GET.

Comment: This is close to what you're asking for - it almost looks like you have to do a string builder.   Which sort of defeats the idea of passing an object.     POST is certainly the best way to handle it -- is there no way you can do it via POST?   It removes the headache of complext object transports.   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585992/mvc-webapi-get-passing-an-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, I sow this question, but precisely I want to avoid to codify manually all members of the class in the URI. Yes, I could use POST, but according the guidelines, POST must be used when you save some data in the server and GET when you simply get data.

Comment: comment area was too long, see my "answer" below.  In short, if you need to feed the server some complex data to get a result, you should be using POST.    To feed it via the querystring is only going to infuse more headache than necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API Get Method with Complex Object as Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049989/web-api-get-method-with-complex-object-as-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example is showing that the GET is passing it a complex object in the call.   Normally, that's just a simple request, and returning the complex object -- that's the "best practice".    If you need to request something by giving it a complex object - it should still be a POST call.    I know the pundits like to think POST/PUT as your change/add for the REST world -- but in the end, frankly there's zero difference between a POST and a GET besides the request body.    If you need to give the server complex data, use the request body (aka POST).   If it's a simple request -- `/api/listofvendors/zone1` - then use a GET.

[Web API Get Method with Complex Object as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049989/web-api-get-method-with-complex-object-as-parameter)

example:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/services/mrf/{mrfnumber}")]                       // GET specific MRF
    public Mrf GetMrfRecord(string mrfnumber) {
        using (var ddc = new MRFDataContext(ConnectionString)) {
            var options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith((Mrf c) => c.MRFParts);    //immediate load related MRFParts
            ddc.LoadOptions = options;

            var mrf = (from u in ddc.Mrfs
                       where u.MrfNum == mrfnumber
                       select u).FirstOrDefault();

            return mrf ?? null;
        }
    }
```